# Initialising C struct expected an expression

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have a C struct with about 17 members `struct settings currentProfile` and would like to initialise it all members to zero. (I have tried this both with the uber-correct struct syntax and with typedef syntax)

To set all members to zero I use `currentProfile = {0}`

at this line the compiler gives the erro `Expected an expression`

Am I initialising correctly?
Thanks

Comment: Please show some code that exhibits the error.

Comment: This concept is clearly mentioned in K n R book

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis 
``settings currentProfile, newProfile
void initProfile (void) {
    currentProfile = {0};
}``

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak would it be unusual to say I havent read K n R?

Comment: @Toby: I did not mean that, you haven't read K n R. What I did mean is, you read it once again, you will come to know. I am sorry if above statement hurt you. But frankly saying I didn't mean your interpretation.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak No I didnt take offence by it, I appreciated the reference. Just idly wondered if many read, or learn from, the K n R book these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing an (invalid) assignment not an initialization.

To initialize your struct object with all members set to `0`:

```
struct settings currentProfile = {0};
```

To set all the members of the struct object to `0` after its declaration:

```
memset(&currentProfile, 0, sizeof currentProfile);
```

Comment: Note that dynamically allocated pointed-to members may need to be `free`d before the `memset` operation to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @moooeeeep, not an issue in initialization!

Comment: @Shahbaz but _may_ be an issue in assignment later on.

Comment: @moooeeeep Or if they are needed they might be stored in temporary pointers and rewritten in the `struct` after the `memset`.

Comment: @ouah, odes this work for declarations of multiple structs like ``settings currentProfile, newProfile = {0};`` ? Ta

Comment: @Toby you have to put explicit initializers in both declarations like this: `struct settings currentProfile = {0}, newProfile = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

memset(pointer_to_struct, 0, size_of_struct);

```
#include <string.h>

struct settings currentProfile;
memset(&currentProfile, 0, sizeof(struct settings));
```

Comment: I did the same but I am getting an error, find the code below. #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct abc
{int x;int y;};
struct abc xyz;
int main(){
memset(&xyz, 1, sizeof(struct xyz));
cout << xyz.x; // giving garbage
return 0;}

Comment: Find the C Code   #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//using namespace std;
struct abc
{int x;int y;};
struct abc xyz;
int main(){
memset(&xyz, 1, sizeof(struct abc));
//memset(&xyz, 1, sizeof(struct xyz)); // Gives error invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct xyz'
printf("xyz.x = %d", xyz.x) ; // giving garbage
return 0;}

Comment: It doesn't print garbage.
memset second arguments is of type int but expect byte (8-bit long number). You are passing 1 so its binary representation is 00000001 => 16843009 is equal to 00000001000000010000000100000001