# Compilation error in function using tokens in C

Tags: c, data-structures, compiler-errors

I defined a structure and created an initialization of that structure in a function but I am always getting an error for no reason.

Structure:

```
typedef struct order 
{
   int ident_o;
   product set_prod[MAX_PRODS_OD]; /* Set of products */
   int state;
}order;
```

Function:

```
order make_order(product s[])
{
    order p1;
    product empty_prod = {0,"",0,0,0,0};
    int i = 0;
    while (i<MAX_PRODS_OD)
    {
        s[i] = empty_prod;
        i++;
    }
    p1 = {0,s,0};   /* creates a product and returns the created product*/
    p1.ident_o = y;
    /*p1.set_prod = *s; */
    return p1;
}
```

I can only compile using this command "gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -pedantic"

and I'm always receiving this error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
     p1 = "{"0,s,0};   /* creates a product and returns the created product*/
```

I don't understand why it's pointing to that token between those quotation marks. The code is correct right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialising C struct expected an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008892/initialising-c-struct-expected-an-expression)

Comment: Not quite because as u can see i initialised each individual part of the struct and still gives me that error

Comment: You have to put p1.ident_o = 0; etc. etc.

Comment: *"... u can see i initialised each individual..."* - no, you didn't. Regarding `p1 = {0,s,0};`, that's not initialization; that's *assignment*, and that form of assignment is not supported in standard C. Initialization looks like what you did two lines in with `product empty_prod = {0,"",0,0,0,0};` . *That* is initialization.

Comment: The important part of the answer is: `You are doing an (invalid) assignment not an initialization`. That is, you can't compound assign to a `struct` variable except during initialisation. After that you need to set each field seperately (or use `memset` if setting to all the same value).

Comment: You *may* be able to use a [*compound literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal),

Comment: OK ive tried to use memset like u said and like kaylum said in the post he linked and it worked thanks but im still not understanding the difference between product p1 = {0,s,0} and product empty_prod = {0,"",0,0,0,0}; for me its the same so if u could explain it to me i would love it.

Comment: @WhozCraig — they could use a compound literal except that they're commanded to use `gcc -ansi` which means `gcc -std=c90` which means no C99 features such as compound literals.  I'm not sure what benefit there is to being taught a 30-year old language.  It seems stupid.  About the only excuse is the MSVC only really supports C90, but that's not a very good reason in my book.

Comment: *"the difference between `product p1 = {0,s,0}`" ...* - that code verbatim doesn't exist *anywhere* in what you posted, and if you can't see that you need to read what you posted again. That would be proper initialization. Your code doesn't do that. Rather, your code is two-step: (1) defines `product p1;`, then later (2) attempts to assign to `p1` via the statement `p1 = {0,s,0};` Definition-with-initialization vs. Definition-then-assignment may seem the same; they're not.

Comment: Please post the definition of `product`

Answer (score 1):

Initializer lists can only be used during initialization, which can only occur when an object is defined.  The only way to directly assign every member of a struct type is by assigning from an expression of a type compatible with that struct type.  You can do this by assigning from another object of that struct type directly (or from an object at a pointer of that struct type), or by using a compound literal.  Here is some code that demonstrates what I'm talking about.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct foo {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
    struct foo foobar = { 0, 5}; // initialization
    struct foo barbaz = { 1, 3};
    struct foo *qwop;
    printf("%d %d\n", foobar.a, foobar.b);

    foobar = barbaz; // assigning from a struct of compatible type
    printf("%d %d\n", foobar.a, foobar.b);

    foobar = (struct foo){24, 99}; // assigning from compound literal
    printf("%d %d\n", foobar.a, foobar.b);

    qwop = &barbaz;
    foobar = *qwop; // assigning from a pointer of struct of compatible type
    printf("%d %d\n", foobar.a, foobar.b);
    return 0;
}
```

Theoretically, you can also use a cast expression, but that should be done with an object that's actually compatible with the struct type, or you risk undefined behavior.